# Disable slide to open menu on AppFramework UI

Tags: menu, slide, intel, jqmobi, appframework

How to disable the slide action to open the left side menu on in AppFramework UI? I don't want the menu to open when slide the finger left to right on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was not difficult after all. Just don't include the javascript plugin af.slidemenu.js.

Another option is set: `$.ui.slideSideMenu = false;`

Comment: That is not working. And I don´t have the plugin included.

Answer (score 2):

To disable slideSide feature, set `$.ui.slideSideMenu=false` or `data-nav="none"` in your required panel.